data showing in request payload, but null in controller requestbody
I am trying simply to pass a string as a requestbody to my controller, every other call works (the same way) but this one gives me null for the parameter inside the requestbody.
The payload is filled correctly.
This is the thymeleaf code
<div>
    <h1>
        Recipe:
        <span id="recipeName" th:text="${recipe.name}"></span>
        <input type="text" id="editRecipeName" class="edit-fields" style="display: none;" th:value="${recipe.name}">

        <button onclick="toggleEditFields(this)">Edit recipe name</button>
        <button class="edit-fields" style="display: none;" th:onclick="editRecipe([[${product.id}]], [[${recipe.id}]])">Save</button>
        <button class="edit-fields" style="display: none;" onclick="cancelEdit(this)">Cancel</button>
    </h1>
</div>

<script>
    function editRecipe(productId, recipeId) {
        var newName = document.getElementById('editRecipeName').value;

        $.ajax({
            url: "/recipes/" + productId + "/" + recipeId,
            type: "PUT",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify({name: newName}),
            success: function (response) {
                alert("Recipe updated successfully!");
                location.reload();
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.error(xhr.responseText);
                alert("Error updating recipe");
            }
        });
    } </script>

and my controller function
@PutMapping("/{productId}/{recipeId}")
public ResponseEntity<Recipe> updateRecipe(@PathVariable Long productId, @PathVariable Long recipeId, @RequestBody UpdateRecipeCommand updateRecipeCommand) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(recipeService.updateRecipe(recipeId, updateRecipeCommand));
}

Where my command look like this
public record UpdateRecipeCommand(String name){
}

I have exactly the same code for updateProduct on a different page, where it works perfectly fine. But I don't understand why its not transfering my name data from payload (correct) to controlller.
To be complete the payload looks like this:
{name: "test"}
and in my controller my command looks like this
UpdateRecipeCommand[name=null]
Any help regarding this will be appreciated. I can share the code for the update productname as well but its literally the same but 'product' instead of 'recipe'and controller function takes one less parameter like this
@PutMapping("/{productId}")
    public ResponseEntity<Product> updateProduct(@PathVariable Long productId, @RequestBody UpdateProductCommand updateProductCommand) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(productService.updateProduct(productId, updateProductCommand));
    }

Thanks

i don't see any issue in above code, i have done a sample app with similar requirements and updated to github check below for more details
https://github.com/prasadram/thymdemo/blob/master/README.md , if you still face issue can you please provide the code base in github so that it's easy to debug
